# What secret hats are there?

Tags: support, winterbash

I notice there are some hats available that aren't on the hat list. What other hats exist, and what do I have to do to unlock them?

Comment: dun dun dun!!!!!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There appear to be 6 hats in [the sprite file](http://hatdash.com/content/img/hats128.png) that are not on the list:

---

## **Lump of Coal**

[image: Coal]
Awarded for a [Question or Answer](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3476/13) Downvote.

---

## **The N00b Hat**

[image: The N00b Hat]
First post by a new user!

---

## **Scrooge Hat**

[image: Scrooge Hat]

Participate in closing a question.

---

## **Braaaains**

[image: Braaaains]

Post a question or answer from an account dead for 30 days before Hat Dash began

---

## **Batman's Cowl**

[image: Batman's Cowl]
*Was intended to be for having three upvoted [arkham-city](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arkham-city) questions or answers, but it was dropped due to time constraints*

---

## **Master Mind**

[image: Master Mind]
Average answer score of at least 5 and at least 5 answers.  This hat was not awarded until HatDash officially ended at 12:00am UTC January 7, 2012.

---

Plus, the hat that you start with:

## **Invisible Hat**

[image: Invisible Hat]
Clicked on a link.

Comment: Batman's Cowl would be having 3 upvoted Batman: Arkham City answers, based off the others.

Comment: If you want to test, go upvote me. :P

Comment: Zombie could very well be related to the Necromancer badge.

Comment: and given that there was already one Community Wiki answer, why did you add another one? :P

Comment: @Powerlord Duh, the *hat*.  :P

Comment: @John Umm, community wiki usually doesn't count as activity.

Comment: @Powerlord Well, I guess we'll find out.

Comment: @Powerlord: I was busy making the images while you posted your answer. I didn't bother to refresh. If it bothers you that much I'll delete this and edit yours though.

Comment: [It appears that the Zombie Hat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/2742124#2742124) is related to a user returning to the site after an absence. Attempting to recruit a patsy to test this theory.

Answer (score 1):

Here, I'll start a Community Wiki answer

- Lump of Coal - Downvote a question, as seen on [LessPopMoreFizz](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/3129/lesspop-morefizz)'s hat rack.