# Lump of coal's hat description is incorrect

Tags: bug, status-completed, winterbash

The description for the *Lump of Coal* hat is

> Downvote a question

Yet I obtained this hat after downvoting [an *answer*](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/37499/buying-a-house-in-markarth-bugged/42132#42132) (10k only).

Comment: my **god!** I for one am terribly offended by this injustice! We should all be given an extra hat for compensation.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The person responsible for this has been severely punished, and the false statements have been corrected.

This is serious business.