# What are the Secret Hats for 2012?

Tags: discussion, winterbash

And how do we get them?

MASSIVE SPOILERS AHEAD.

([2011 Edition](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3455/what-secret-hats-are-there))

Answer (score 13):

- **[Cake is Not a Lie](http://winterba.sh/cake-is-not-a-lie):** Edit a post which goes on to earn 5 upvotes.
  [A cupcake that goes on your head http://cdn.prom.sstatic.net/WinterBash/img/1900909705-128.png](http://cdn.prom.sstatic.net/WinterBash/img/1900909705-128.png)

---

- **[The Abby](http://winterba.sh/the-abby):** Participate in closing a post.
  [A red bowtie http://cdn.prom.sstatic.net/WinterBash/img/1432640864-128.png](http://cdn.prom.sstatic.net/WinterBash/img/1432640864-128.png)

---

- **[N00b hat](http://winterba.sh/n00b-hat):** Downvote a post.
  [A multicolored propeller beanie http://cdn.prom.sstatic.net/WinterBash/img/286828013-128.png](http://cdn.prom.sstatic.net/WinterBash/img/286828013-128.png)

---

- **[Gotta catch'em all](http://winterba.sh/gotta-catch-em-all)**: Earn 15 other hats.
  [A white/red baseball cap with a Poké Ball on it http://cdn.prom.sstatic.net/WinterBash/img/426334077-128.png](http://cdn.prom.sstatic.net/WinterBash/img/426334077-128.png)

---

- **[Shiver Me Timbers](http://winterba.sh/shiver-me-timbers)**: Beat the current accepted answer of 3 upvotes or more by 2x as many votes.
  [A pirate hat http://cdn.prom.sstatic.net/WinterBash/img/1423700688-128.png](http://cdn.prom.sstatic.net/WinterBash/img/1423700688-128.png)

---

- **[And I Feel Fine](http://winterba.sh/and-i-feel-fine)**: Post or vote on December 21.
  [A golden Mayan mask http://cdn.prom.sstatic.net/WinterBash/img/136881030-128.png](http://cdn.prom.sstatic.net/WinterBash/img/136881030-128.png)

---

- **[Bushido](http://winterba.sh/bushido)**: Earn the necromancer badge.
  [A Japanese Bushido mask http://cdn.prom.sstatic.net/WinterBash/img/1529797420-128.png](http://cdn.prom.sstatic.net/WinterBash/img/1529797420-128.png)

---

- **[Epic Punyon Beard](http://winterba.sh/epic-punyon-beard)**: It is the dawning of the age of Aquarius./It was hairy. (wut? [Relevant Meta.SO post's here.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/159782/the-mysterious-epic-punyon-beard) I think a mod has to manually give this one, and it seems to only be given out on Meta.SO. They say that it's earnable and at least one non-mod has it ([dmck](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/192625/dmck)), but that doesn't mean that it's possible to earn it without them manually awarding it.)
  [Long brown hair and a brown beard http://cdn.prom.sstatic.net/WinterBash/img/2096626522-128.png](http://cdn.prom.sstatic.net/WinterBash/img/2096626522-128.png)

Comment: Users who have unlocked secret hats should link images of them.

Comment: @Wipqozn Kind of way ahead of you.

Comment: Crap, the images kind of have huge margins. Feel free to crop them

Comment: [Here's a set of images which appear to have some secret hats](http://cdn.prom.sstatic.net/WinterBash/img/sprite-128.png) but they may or may not be real, and they're not all of the secret hats (note the currently above hats dont' appear on that sprite)

Comment: I have all four of these now, what other hidden hats are there?

Comment: @BenBrocka I don't think that picture you linked contains actual secret hats. None of the secret hats that have been found appear in it, and all of the images that are in it and are not known hats would be stupid as hats.

Comment: @murgatroid99 I agree since none of them have come up yet; it may just be another Easter egg

Comment: Someone not lazy edit this in http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/159515/how-do-you-get-a-pirate-hat

Comment: Someone else not lazy: http://winterba.sh/bushido

Comment: I already got Necro, does this mean I have to get another Necro to get the hat?

Comment: @Retrosaur yes you have to get it while the event is on